# Redirect a stream to console and a log file but not to output stream

Tags: powershell

A function provides some feedback (via Write-Verbose), processes an object, and then puts that object back to the output stream.

```
function f([parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True [System.Object] $obj)
{
     Write-Verbose "Processing obj"
     do-something $obj
     $obj
}
```

I need the feedback message go to the console and the log file but not into the pipeline, something like

```
function f([parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)][System.Object] $obj)
{
     # Show message on the console and write it to the log file.
     Write-Verbose "Processing obj" 4>&1 | Tee-Object log.txt
     do-something $obj
     $obj
}
```

The above will not work with command like this:

```
 obj1,obj2,obj3,... | f | do-something-cmdlet
```

because Tee-Object will write all verbose messages to output stream and will flow to the next pipeline.

Is there a way to get this done or I need a 'log' function that will print each message twice - to console and to a file?

Comment: Couldn't you just separate this into two lines? First line output the message and then the next line write to the file? `Write-Verbose "Processing obj"; "Processing obj" | Add-Content log.txt`

Comment: yes, I can do that. Seems like there is no one liner for this.

Comment: Utilize `Write-Host` if you don't want anything ending up on a stream.

Comment: Also, why are you redirecting the verbose message?  Use the `-Verbose` switch when calling the function to avoid your redirect issue with `Tee-Object`

Comment: I want the verbose message go to console and to log file. Write-Host "message" | Tee-Object log.txt will end up in the output stream because Tee-Object will send it to a file and then to output stream. Actually, Write-Host will not even send it down to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I utilize a logging function for things like this.

```
Function Write-Log
{
    Param(
      [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]
      [String]$Message
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Host $Message
        $Message | Out-File -FilePath $global:LogFile -Append
    }
}
```